# Laravel - modify response text for deactivated user

Tags: laravel

I'm using Laravel  8.27.0

And I got the following function inside my LoginController in order to keep deactivated / deleted users from logging in. If some has a timestamp set in the field "deleted_at" in the user table he won't be able to log in.

```
protected function credentials(Request $request)
    {
        return [
            'email' => $request->input('email'),
            'password' => $request->input('password'),
            'deleted_at' => null
        ];
    }
```

The function works fine .  My only problem is that if a deactivated tries to log in he gets this message

```
These credentials do not match our records.
```

Which isn't the message that I need. I want to display something like "Your account has been deleted" but only if a user has the deleted_at flag set for his user account. If someone has an active user account and gets his credentials wrong they still need to get the above mentioned message. Is it possible to change the message for this situation ?

Comment: If you are using soft delete method then the default login will throw _These credentials do not match our records_, because  eloquent ignore the `deleted_at` column on login, so the user doesn't exist. You need to create another column, as like _status_ or something, if you want to use the default authentication

Comment: I changed the column and use "deactivated_at" instead. But I get the same error message. How do I change the error message but only if the deactivated_at is set ?

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if this is good practice but I found a working solution by adding the two following functions to my LoginController

```
protected function credentials(Request $request)
    {
        return [
            'email' => $request->input('email'),
            'password' => $request->input('password'),
            'deleted_at' => null
        ];
    }
    
protected function sendFailedLoginResponse(Request $request)
{
    
    $User = User::where("email","=",$request->email)->first();
    

    
    if($User->deleted_at === null){
        
          throw ValidationException::withMessages([
        $this->username() => [trans('auth.failed')],
    ]);
        
        
    }
    
    
    if($User->deleted_at != null){
        
          throw ValidationException::withMessages([
        $this->username() => [trans('auth.user_deleted')],
    ]);
        
        
    }
    
  
}
```

And then I added the line

```
'user_deleted' => 'Your account has been suspended',
```

to the file /resources/lang/en/auth.php